# bundle exec rake <command> takes forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake, bundle

when I run a `bundle exec rake <command>`, it's taking me forever to load the gems and finish the task on production. By forever, I'm referring to 20+ minutes, which is really bizarre. For example when I run

```
bundle exec rake --trace db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

it takes me more than 10 minutes to finally see the `** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)` output.
Is there any way to debug this and make my rake tasks faster?

Comment: Which version of rails are you working on ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder I'm using Rails 3.2

Comment: And the application you are working on is a new vanilla application ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder nope, it's actually been maintained for a long time. We're migrating servers right now. The mentioned tasks on our current server setting work perfectly fine with normal time. I'm trying to set up an AWS environment with our codebase and capistrano and while everything else is fine, the bundle exec time is a no-go.

Comment: I have had the same issue with 3.2 , but it used to take up maximum 3-4 minutes .

Comment: There's this NewRelic gem , you can add it to your application . It shows live statistics of where exactly the application is slowing down on it's dashboard.

Comment: Have a look at this one too , might help - http://rakeroutes.com/blog/increase-rails-performance-with-database-indexes/